# Robocopy cannot find specific directory

Tags: robocopy

I am migrating our file server from 2008 to 2012R2.
Currently i am trying to copy all folders and files to our new server but the command isnt working correctly.

Here is what i am using:

```
robocopy G: D:\ /e /zb /COPY:DATSOU /r:3 /w:1 /v/ /eta /log+:C:\robocopy\copyreport.txt /tee /sec /tbd
```

But for some reason its NOT working.. it cant find the specific path.
I checked and double checked and im 100% sure the paths are working and are correct.. i had an error before with the log file but resolved that.

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Actual error: `2015/04/22 11:24:56 ERROR 3 (0X00000003) Accessing Source Directory G:\ The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Please put the actual error message in your question.

Comment: 2015/04/22 11:24:56 ERROR 3 (0X00000003) Accessing Source Directory G:\ The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Having a similar issue. Did you resolve?? Issue seems to be with the DATSOU command. I am running cmd as admin, amd a local admin, AND am part of the admin Domain group that controls the share server.